# Unity3D UGUI Canvas Gizmo

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui, unity3d-ui

Is it possible to draw Gizmos (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gizmos.html) in the scene view.. but overlaying the UGUI Canvas (within the scene view) and not particularly in world space?  I'm looking to outline some UI elements in the scene view more fully than the vanilla Unity RectTransform is shown there.

We looked at using https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gizmos.DrawGUITexture.html but that appears to fall-back on old-style UI layout and doesn't account for the multiple different Render Modes the UI Canvas can be set to.

Answer (score 2):

No.

You need to create the gizmos yourself in the game. There are some plugins in the asset store that provide re-implemented gizmos. You can have a look at them.

To show a 3D object in a texture, you need another camera and a [`RenderTexture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderTexture.html) asset. Let the camera look at the gizmos you created and assign the `RenderTexture` to [`Camera.targetTexture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-targetTexture.html).

To show the texture on the UGUI Canvas, create a [`RawImage`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.RawImage.html), then assign the `RenderTexture` to it.

Comment: Sorry... I didn't word my question very well.  I'm looking to show the gizmos over top of UI elements in the scene view.  Not in the game view itself.

Comment: You also need to do the same thing.